# Dúvidas sobre composição de classes ou herança

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, composição

Estou com algumas dúvidas nessa composição entre o `ClienteJuridico` e ClienteFisico com a `NotaFiscal`. Eu dei uma pesquisada e vi que da pra instanciar os `objetos` dessas classes dentro de outra, no caso seria a composição, mas como eu poderia herdar os atributos dessas classes na classe `NotaFiscal`?

[image: UML]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho um pouco estranho `ClienteJuridico`, e `ClienteFisico`, herdar de `Pessoa`. Não totalmente absurdo, mas parece conceitualmente errado, talvez seja só questão de nome. Será que um dia essas pessoas não poderão ser fornecedores ou terem outros papéis? Ficará esquisito. Mas esse não é o problema.

Você tem que decidir, quer herdar ou quer compor? Elas são essencialmente antagônicas. Uma `NotaFiscal` **é um** `ClienteJuridico`? Como? Não consigo imaginar como isto é possível, então herança parece descartada. A composição parece adequada. Mas tem problemas. Não consigo imaginar porque um cliente deva ter referência a um objeto de nota fiscal. Também acho estranho a NF permitir ter tanto CPF quanto CNPJ.

A herança de `NotaFiscal` em `Vendas` parece mais absurda ainda (nem sei bem o que esta classe faz). Minha sugestão é rever seu conceito do que é herança. Tem material sobre o assunto aqui no site.

E percebo outros problemas no modelo, mas são detalhes que não são foco da pergunta.

Note que o uso do termo atributo está correto porque isto é UML, mas quando for se referenciar na linguagem [isso chama-se campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).